# Lambda Sort :According to Multiple elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

i want to sort: list of tuples need to sorted with multiple elements in array.

An input array of tuples need to be sorted according to multiple elements in the array. For some of the indices, it needs to be sorted in non-decreasing order: (denoted by a 0) and for Others it needs to be sorted in non-increasing mder (denoted by 1) In the editor below. you need to write the lambda function to achieve the same.

Take,for example. the input array to be `arr = [(1,2,3),(3,2,1),(4,2,1), (6,4,3)]` with number of elements being `n=4` and number of elements in each tuple being m=3 . Let,the input indices on which this array is to be sorted be `indices =[(2,0), (O, 1)]`, with length being `k = 2`. This means that we need to sort our array based on index 2 in non-decreasing Order and then based on index 0 in non-decreasing Order. First. sorting based on `index 2` in non-decreasing order: we get `[(3,2,1),(4,2,1),(1,2, 3),(6,4,3)]` and then, sorting based on `index 0` in non-decreasing Order we get `[(4,2,1),[3,2,1),(6,4,3),(1,2,3)]`.

#### Note:

You need to implement stable sort i.e in case of tie between elements at position `i,j` such that `i<=j` and then the position in the sorted array for these elements is `fi,fj`, then `fi<=fj`.

#### Function Description:

Complete the function `indexSort` in the editor below. You Just Need to write the lambda function required to achieve this.

`arr[arr[0],....arr[n-1]]`: an array of tuples
indices: an array of two elements tuple

#### Sample Case 1:

```
arr=[(1,2,3),(3,2,1),(4,2,1), (6,4,3)]
indices=[(2,0), (O, 1)]
Output: [(4,2,1),[3,2,1),(6,4,3),(1,2,3)]
```

#### Explanation:

- Sort by `index 2` in non-decreasing order:`[(3,2,1),(4,2,1),(1,2,3),(6,4,3)]`
- Sort by `index 0` in non increasing order:`[(4,2,1),(3,2,1),(6,4,3),(1,2,3)]`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Are you trying to make the built-in library sort do this, or do you have to write your own sorting code?

Comment: i got this question in my interview,but unable to solve it.i just want to solve this question .  def indexSort(arr,indices):
                        arr.sort(key=  //code   )

Answer (score 0):

The problem expects you to write a `lambda` function to produce the keys used to sort your list of tuples. That's not too hard to do based on the `indicies` parameter to the outer function. I'd use a list comprehension, with negated values for an index if the second value in indicies is non-zero:

```
def indexSort(arr, indicies):
    arr.sort(key=lambda tup: [tup[i] if d == 0 else -tup[i] for i, d in indicies])
```